# Sorting a list of tuples by date

Tags: python, sorting, date, tuples

I would like to sort and return a section of a tuple with it sorted by date.

I'd only like to sort the first to the 4th record (tuple[:3]) and print it.

```
tuple = [('Dec 1, 2010', '7.41', '7.60', '7.37'), 
         ('Dec 4, 2010', '7.41', '7.60', '7.37'), 
         ('Dec 2, 2010', '7.41', '7.60', '7.37'), 
         ('Dec 20, 2010', '7.41', '7.60', '7.37'), 
         ('Dec 16, 2010', '7.41', '7.60', '7.37'), 
         ('Jan 2, 2011', '7.41', '7.60', '7.37')]
```

I tried:

```
import operator
sorted(tuple[:3], key=operator.itemgetter('date'), reverse=True)
```

But, it returned the error "TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str.

Comment: Don't call the list `tuple`. It shadows the built-in `tuple`, a container.

Answer (score 8):

Why are you getting by `date`? isn't the first element of the tuple what you are looking for?

```
sorted(records[:3], key=operator.itemgetter(0), reverse=True)
```

By the way, you should transform the string to an actual date before you compare them. Maybe:

```
from datetime import datetime
def get_date(record):
     return datetime.strptime(record[0], "%b %d, %Y")
sorted(records[:3], key=get_date, reverse=True)
```

I've renamed `tuple` to `records`. As others have pointed out, by using `tuple` you are shadowing a type constructor; equally important: it's a list not a tuple, the variable should be plural (as it stores a collection), and it should have a meaningful name.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `[]` is not a tuple, it's called a list (see [this post on daniweb.com](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/post669420.html#post669420)).

Secondly, in a `dictionary` you link a `key` to a `value`. Since a list is one-dimensional, you can only get a value by requesting a indice.

```
>> dic = {'date' : 'value', 'bla' : 'foo'}
>> dic['date']
value
>> dic['bla']
foo

>> list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>> list[0]
a
>> list[2]
c
```

You most likely want to convert your dates to `datetime.datetime` objects, before sorting them. As they are strings (in your example), they will be alphabetically sorted *not* by date.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're asking for the key `'date'`. That would only work if the data elements were dictionaries with `'date'` in them.

As tokland pointed out, you need to use `0` since that's the element of the tuples you're asking for, the first one.

Also, be sure not to actually name your `tuple` "tuple": That's the name of the type itself, and you don't want to replace it with another value.

Comment: He has a list of tuples, actually.

Comment: Right, I've since noticed that also.

Answer (score 0):

The text `'date'` is not magical. `operator.itemgetter` uses whatever it's passed as an index into whatever it's looking at. It does not try to understand what `'date'` means.

`'date'` is a string. A `dict` has keys that are strings. You have `tuple`s in your list. A `tuple` has keys that are integers, starting at 0.

Furthermore, using `key` for a sort just says "once you've gotten the key from each item, sort the items according the key values, *interpreting the key values normally*". The beginning item of each of your `tuple` s is not magically some kind of Date object just because they look like dates to you and me. They are strings, and they will be compared like strings.

@tokland shows how to set up code for the operation "given one of these tuples, grab the start element and convert it into a date, using the `datetime` module". Then he calls the sort using this operation for the key.